# Android HCE : Off host aids are not routed to SE

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, hce

I am working on a wallet application with Secure element. Recently I updated our payment code to include OffHostApduService for KitKat OS. I registered all card AIDs to use off host card emulation. But when we try payment the aids are not directed to SE. Got the below error on a HTC M8 phone:

```
E/HostEmulationManager(19573): AID that was meant to go off-host was routed to host. Check routing table configuration.
```

Below is the offhostapduservice entry in manifest file:

```
<service android:exported="true" android:name=".MyOffHostApduService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.OFF_HOST_APDU_SERVICE"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.off_host_apdu_service" android:resource="@xml/apduservice"/>
    </service>
```

This is the apdu service xml file:

```
<offhost-apdu-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:apduServiceBanner="@drawable/payment_banner"
android:description="@string/servicedesc" >

<aid-group
    android:category="payment"
    android:description="@string/paymentGroup" >
    // all aids go here
</aid-group>
```

Really appreciate any ideas on this issue.

Thanks